# Exchange 2003 - LDAP access to public calendar folder (via php)?

Tags: php, ldap, exchange-server-2003

Is it possible to access exchange server 2003 public calendar entries via LDAP?

I am currently working with LDAP in PHP and authenticating against active directory for login, but now I need to access a public calendar in the exchange server to read the calendar entries in there.

If no, do you have any other suggestions on how I might get the public calendar entries?